# How can I optimize performance when using SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate to avoid unnecessary rebuilds of slivers below it in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

- The SliverPersistentHeader is causing slivers below it to rebuild unnecessarily when scrolling downward and when the header touches the upper end of screen then it rebuilds.
- The HomePage widget includes a SliverPersistentHeader and a SliverList containing multiple TaskCard widgets.
- The SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate returns a Container with a Column containing a Text widget and a TaskFilterBar widget.
- Despite implementing shouldRebuild to return false, the slivers below the persistent header still rebuild.

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.3007], locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 3.16.5 on channel stable at C:\Flutter\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 78666c8dc5 (4 weeks ago), 2023-12-19 16:14:14 -0800
    • Engine revision 3f3e560236
    • Dart version 3.2.3
    • DevTools version 2.28.4

[✓] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\vaibh\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[✗] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    ✗ Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.85.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\vaibh\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.80.0

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • Redmi Note 9 Pro Max (mobile) • adb-c920ad7c-aY6Kpa._adb-tls-connect._tcp • android-arm64  • Android 12 (API 31)
    • Windows (desktop)             • windows                                   • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows
      [Version 10.0.22621.3007]
    • Chrome (web)                  • chrome                                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome
      120.0.6099.217
    • Edge (web)                    • edge                                      • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge
      120.0.2210.133

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.
```

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
   HomePage({super.key});

  final TaskSliverPersistentHeaderDelegate headerDelegate = TaskSliverPersistentHeaderDelegate();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<ImageCarouselBloc>(
          create: (context) => ImageCarouselBloc(),
        ),
        BlocProvider<TaskBloc>(
          create: (context) => TaskBloc(),
        ),
        // Add more BlocProviders for other blocs if needed
      ],
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 3.w, right: 3.w),
            child: CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: ImageCarousel()
                ),
                SliverPersistentHeader(
                    pinned: true,
                    floating: true,
                    delegate: headerDelegate
                ),
                SliverList(
                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                            (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return TaskCard(
                            isFeatured: false,
                          );
                        }, childCount: 8)),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class TaskSliverPersistentHeaderDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  static const double persistentHeaderHeight = 101.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 3.3.w, top: 1.h),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                "Tasks",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 2.5.h, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          TaskFilterBar(), // Assuming TaskFilterBar is a widget you want to include
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => persistentHeaderHeight;

  @override
  double get minExtent => persistentHeaderHeight;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false; // Only rebuild when the delegate changes
  }
}
```

I want the SliverPersistentHeader to be of a fixed size ,i have given the min & max values same but i think that the reload is because of it so tel me how tto make it const or fixed size.

I tried the wrap the slivers with NestedScrollView but it didn't solve the problem.
Please anyone who has knowledge about it , help !

Comment: Are you talking about the Delegate Instance ? Yes tried to shift it in the build ,still no change !